# report pie chart missing tons of values

Tags: report-chart

I made a report on Accounts summarized by Type. Then I added a pie chart to display a record count of each Type. The pie chart is not showing all of the types. I have attached a screenshot below illustrating the problem.

[image: the actual list of type values from the report]

[image: pie chart missing scores of type values]

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purple slice ("Other") represents values under a certain threshold (< 4%). There's an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrM5AAK) to allow us to customize the threshold for those that would like more control. There currently *is no fix* without writing Visualforce code and including it as a custom component on your dashboard.